# Android Geofencingclient ApiException 1004:

Tags: android, android-geofence

I have been trying to implement Geofencing for an android app, and right now after initializing the `GeoFenceRequest` as per Google's Documentation and then adding it with the `GeoFencingClient`

```
geofencingClient.addGeofences(geoFenceRequest, geofencePendingIntent).addOnSuccessListener {
        Log.d(TAG, "GeoFence Added")
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        Log.d(TAG, "GeoFence Failed to Add")
    }
```

i get this error

```
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 1004:
```

and i cannot find any documentation describing anything related to it at all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

found the solution
apparently 1004 is the app lacks permissions from the device, i was missing the background location permission for android 10.
this is the documentation for the status codes:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofenceStatusCodes

Comment: Which permission , you have missed, i have stuck in the same problem

Comment: i was running on android 10 test device, and it required the ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission

Comment: @MahmoudOmara HI I am facing the same issue in android 10 device, I have added the permission ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION  but still getting the same issue with statusCode 1004

Comment: when the app asked for permission, did u set it to "allow in background"?

Answer (score 4):

I changed my app's location setting from

```
ALLOWED ONLY WHILE IN USE
```

to

```
ALLOWED ALL THE TIME
```

and it worked.

[image]

Comment: @QadurHussain can you check my post as well